# How can we access Azure storage table data into SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

I have created Azure storage table and its URL is https://Testteams.table.core.windows.net/TestTable.

Now, I want to access it's a record into our SharePoint Online by SharePoint hosted app.

Can it be possible by logic app or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities. Here would be my recommended alternatives:

- Provider Hosted app which connects to the Azure table and presents it
  on your SharePoint site.
- Build a custom Web API which serves the table, or use the Table Service REST API, and consume that data from you SharePoint hosted app.
- Build a web job in Azure which copies the data into your SharePoint list or similar. Then you can show the data with a built-in list view or your custom SharePoint hosted app or just javascript.
- Access the data in SharePoint via External List from a [SQL Azure table with Business Connectivity Services](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-an-external-list-from-a-sql-azure-table-with-business-connectivity-services-and-secure-store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95) (I'm uncertain of this one)